# Show product updated date in Magento

Tags: date, magento, product

I want to show the date of last update (not creation date) in a Magento product page.

```
<?php echo $_product->getUpdatedAt();?> IS WORKING
```

But I don't want to show the TIME — only the DATE.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

Ashley's solution should work, but you may have to wrap it in [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) first

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_product->getUpdatedAt()));
```

I would recommend using Magento's date model to get the time in your timezone (it will also take care of your timestamp).

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date("Y-m-d", $_product->getUpdatedAt());
```

Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Date.php`

```
<?php

class Mage_Core_Model_Date
{
    /**
     * Converts input date into date with timezone offset
     * Input date must be in GMT timezone
     *
     * @param  string $format
     * @param  int|string $input date in GMT timezone
     * @return string
     */
    public function date($format = null, $input = null)
    {
        if (is_null($format)) {
            $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
        }

        $result = date($format, $this->timestamp($input));
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts input date into timestamp with timezone offset
     * Input date must be in GMT timezone
     *
     * @param  int|string $input date in GMT timezone
     * @return int
     */
    public function timestamp($input = null)
    {
        if (is_null($input)) {
            $result = $this->gmtTimestamp();
        } else if (is_numeric($input)) {
            $result = $input;
        } else {
            $result = strtotime($input);
        }

        $date      = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($result);
        $timestamp = $date->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP) + $date->get(Zend_Date::TIMEZONE_SECS);

        unset($date);
        return $timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code 

echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date("Y-m-d", $_product->getUpdatedAt());

did exactly the job!

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

Magento stores the updatedAt attribute as a mysql timestamp. You need to use normal PHP date functions to show the date portion only.

e.g.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $_product->getUpdatedAt());
```

There are no specific magento functions for this, just simple PHP, although you could use some of the built in locale methods to show the correct date for the users timezone but again, this could done with good old fashioned PHP.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. **1.** There is Magento functionaltity for this and **2.** mysql timestamp is _not_ the same as UNIX timestamp, which is used by `date()`